# Plot in one graph 2 sets of 3 variables with reversed y axis

Tags: r, variables, graphics, double

I have 2 tables, each one with 3 variables and a monthly value:

## table1

```
x1 x2 x3
6  10 4   #jan
8  12 3   #feb
2  13 5   #mar
1  17 2   #apr
9  10 7   #may
5  15 1   #jun
6  19 3   #jul
3  13 8   #aug
6  18 2   #sep
8  11 4   #oct
2  15 6   #nov
1  17 2   #dec
```

## table2

```
x1 x2 x3
3  11 1   #jan
5  15 6   #feb
7  11 2   #mar
3  16 4   #apr
7  12 5   #may
4  13 3   #jun
3  17 5   #jul
4  15 9   #aug
7  16 4   #sep
9  13 5   #oct
4  17 6   #nov
2  14 4   #dec
```

now I want to compare the 2 datasets in one graph in this style:

[image]

as you cann see, the first two variables should be adjusted to the standard direction of the y axis (increasing upwards) but the third variable should have a reverse y axis at the right side, so you can see it at the upper part of the graph.

how can I achieve this with both sets in the plot for comparison?

Comment: What did you try so far? What do you use for plotting?

Comment: I tried "scale_y_reverse()" with ggplot and it does reverse the y axis but no idea how to have one normal y axis at the left side for two variables and one reversed y axis at the right side for the other variable

Comment: What I do usually is to scale the third variable to have y-values where I want it to appear, and then I draw a custom axis on the right with `axis()` where I do the inverse scaling to have the axis thick mark where I want them to be